# My eclipse keep saying "The value of the field is not used"

Tags: java, class, constructor, boolean, getter-setter

ı have a (boolean)hasDriverLicence variable in my Person class . I created getter and setter methods and ı used hasDriverLicence in the person constructor but my eclipse saying "The value of the field  Person.hasDriverLicence is not used."  Here is the code :

```
public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String gender, Calendar birthDate, String maritalStatus,
        String hasDriverLicence) throws Exception {

    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;

    setGender(gender);
    setMaritalStatus(maritalStatus);
    setHasDriverLicence(hasDriverLicence);
```

and here is the getter and setter :

```
public void setHasDriverLicence(String hasDriverLicence) throws Exception {

    if (!(hasDriverLicence.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) && !(hasDriverLicence.equalsIgnoreCase("No")))

        throw new Exception("Wrong input, please type Yes or No");

    if (hasDriverLicence.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

        this.hasDriverLicence = true;

    }

    else if (hasDriverLicence.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {

        this.hasDriverLicence = false;

    }
}

public String getHasDriverLicence() {

    if (this.hasDriverLicence = true)

        return "Yes";

    if (this.hasDriverLicence = false)

        return "No";

    else

        return "";
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether I should just close as typo, but my answer's a little longer than a comment. Probably a gazillon dupes around too, if someone bothers to find one.

Comment: Just for the record: that "has driver licence" should be a boolean, not a string. The fact that you want to print "yes" when that field is true is about formatting. Your code mixes that. The formatting should live in a different place, and as said: that field should have type boolean!

Comment: FWIW, just make a oneliner from `getHasDriverLicence()` --> `return this.hasDriverLicense ? "Yes" : "No"; `

Comment: Don't use `Exception` unless you have an existing API contract that requires it. `IllegalArgumentException` is the correct choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the getter. 
Your `if` conditions actually set the value of the instance field, instead of checking for it:

```
if (this.hasDriverLicence = true)
```

This should be:

```
if (this.hasDriverLicence == true)
```

Or better simply:

```
if (this.hasDriverLicence) {
    // ...
// no need for a separate if statement for the opposite condition,
// and you can only have two states here
else { 

    // ...
}
```

The variable is therefore assigned but never used in your code.

**Elaboration**

The reason why the single `=` compiles, but the IDE gives you a warning claiming the variable is never used, is because **the assignment operator returns the assigned value**.

For instance, the statement:

```
myVariable = 1
```

... returns `1`.

Therefore, when you are incorrectly checking for an assignment (`=`) rather than primitive equality (`==`), you will always check for the *value* of your assignment (in your case, `true` in the first condition which will always fulfill, `false` in the second, which will therefore never fulfill).

Comment: Even better would not be to have this manual mapping of strings. "has driver licence" is already saying on the naming level that the information should be boolean, not a string.

Comment: @GhostCat totally agree, but there's only so much I can be arsed to fix :D

Comment: @GhostCat hehe thanks. As mentioned in the comments, I suspect there's plenty of dupes out there, at least by loose criteria. Expect this will get closed soon anyway.

Comment: What a joke ... one "=" character changes everything thank you for the help.

Comment: Also ı can't make hasDriverLicence with the type of boolean it must be string .

Comment: @AhmetFarukYılmaz you're welcome, see also my elaboration in the answer for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try rebuilding your workspace. I am not able to see the issue with the above mentioned code.